# Why can't I get into my WiFi?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion DV6000...The WiFi does not work and the only way I can connect is through Ethernet... I go under the Software and Updates and then the Additional Drivers and I have no drivers that can be found... Another thing is that I want to install the drivers through my USB stick but I don't know how... Is there anything I can do to avoid the Ethernet connection and install these updates without the internet? And specifically what driver would I need to connect to my WiFi so I can get the other Updates? I'm mostly new to Ubuntu and I am confused on what I should do... I need what I need to do simplified... Please and Thank You...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you know if you wi-fi target is supported?
If you have dual-boot with windows try to enable the wi-fi connection and go back to ubuntu, sometimes it works. You can also push super(windows) and look "drivers" you iniciate -Additional drivers and via ethernet get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in the past...

i think it's broadcom additional drivers, i found 4 in the past 3 did not work and 1 yes if it dont work... try this...i dont know if this work but try to run your laptop with installation usb stick or cd|dvd, run tryout session and try turn on wifi, installation image have more drivers included. If it work re-install ubuntu with wifi on.